how properly overload function definition to cover specific type for T
Here is simple synthetic function
function test(input) {
    if (typeof input === 'number') {
        return 'a'
    } else {
        return input
    }
}

I want to type it but cannot figure out approach. The best I was able to get is:
function test<T extends number>(input: T): string;
function test<T>(input: T): T;
function test(input) {
    if (typeof input === 'number') {
        return 'a'
    } else {
        return input
    }
}

const a = [test('2'), test(2), test(null), test(true)] as const
//    ^? a: readonly ['2', string, null, true]
// looks valid

const b = [test<string>('2'), test<boolean>(true)] as const
//    ^? b: readonly [string, boolean]
// I can control/generalize types!

The blot on the landscape for that solution looks like that:

Parameter 'input' implicitly has an 'any' type.

What am I missing here? How to make Typescript happy while keeping types consistent and reliable?

Does using function test(input: unknown) { … } for the implementation signature solve the issue? The implementation signature’s parameters need annotations, but an explicit return type isn’t necessary there.

Please [edit] the question so that the first signature is just function test(t: number): string;... it shouldn't be generic if T shows up only once and in the parameter list, and Number is not the correct type to use. Once you fix those you still have the same question about implicit any, which @jsejcksn's comment correctly addresses... and then we can see if there should be an answer written or if there's an existing question this duplicates.

@jsejcksn unknown makes error disappeared, but tbh I'm seeing this pattern for the first time. Is it a typical way to handle overload with generic?

@jcalz right. number vs Number. Fixed.

^ @skyboyer Yes, annotations are always needed for parameters in the implementation signature. The type of each parameter should be at least as wide as the union of every possible type for the same parameter in all of the overload signatures. Because T is unconstrained in the generic overload signature, unknown is the appropriate type in the implementation signature.

^ Would you like to see that as an answer? Am I still missing something?

@jsejcksn yes, plz make it an answer. imo approach looks sufficient, I just am not experienced enough to be sure on that.

Each individual overload signature represents a possible variation of parameter types and associated return type for the function. The implementation of the function must recognize all of these possible variations, so the appropriate type for any given parameter in the implementation signature is a union of all of the types used for that parameter in the overload signatures.
Your function has two overload signatures, one with a generic type that is constrained by number (so input is expected to be some kind of number type)…
function test<T extends number>(input: T): string;

…and one that uses an unconstrained generic type parameter…
function test<T>(input: T): T;

…which means that it could be any type, and is effectively unknown.
This means that the type for the input parameter in the implementation signature should be unknown (because unknown absorbs other types in a union) — and you can simply annotate it to satisfy the compiler:
function test<T extends number>(input: T): string;
function test<T>(input: T): T;
function test(input: unknown) {
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Annotate the parameter in the implementation signature
  if (typeof input === 'number') {
    return 'a'
  } else {
    return input
  }
}

TS Playground

thank you for such a detailed explanation!
